# Xpath - Extract an email address from a long string but excluding the rest of the sting

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I use xpath.  I want to match the email only (and not the entire string) using xpath.

So say the string is:

`<p> You can email me at andy.pandy@gmail.com </p>`

Most of the answers here cite something on the lines of `//p[contains(., '@')]`

However, this will return the entire text within the `<p>` tag.  I want to only return `andy.pandy@gmail.com` excluding the rest.

Is this possible using xpath?

Comment: You may use an regex `([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)` to get the email address in your string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your XML looks something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<data>
    <p>notanemail</p>
    <p>email@example.com</p>
    <p>nothing</p>
</data>
```

You can call:

```
XElement xmlData = XElement.Load("mails.xml");
var emailList = xmlData.XPathSelectElements(@"//p[contains(., '@')]")
   .Select(p => p.Value)
   .ToList();
```